# Google Places API for Android not retrieving place details ["error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized]

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I am developing an android application which will show current location and nearby places details.

I created a project and Google places API Key for Android from console.developers.google.com/apis

Everything is working fine except place details. I am getting this error. I have been reading articles, threads from stackoverflow for 4 hours but could not solve this error. I have added the error message screenshot 
[Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ord0c.png)

I have enabled Google places for android and Google places for web service APIs. Still no luck. Here is snippet of Place details retrieval code.

```
private void ShowNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nearbyPlacesList.size(); i++) {
        //Log.d("onPostExecute","Entered into showing locations");
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = nearbyPlacesList.get(i);
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lat"));
        //Log.d("onPostExecute",lat+"");
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lng"));
        //Log.d("onPostExecute",lng+"");
        String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
        Log.d("onPostExecute",placeName);
        String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");
        Log.d("onPostExecute",vicinity);

        String reference = googlePlace.get("reference");
        Log.d("onPostExecute",reference);

        placeDetailsUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=";
        placeDetailsUrl+=reference;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(placeDetailsUrl);
        sb.append("&sensor=false");
        sb.append("&key=API_KEY");
        // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place details
        PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();

        // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
        placesTask.execute(sb.toString());
        Log.d("onPostExecute",sb.toString());

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
    }
}
```

Here is a sample link to search for place details with key and sensor: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CmRRAAAAWJCg5jPBI1kI4dISUrbklGFJFDaFXw_LdwNrxwZ26DxKoaGtS20rOK8bVtgWffurXfF3jAp4zU-2ULkEhcLAkOyCEy0I5etHB10Kp58j3juQz0yBT94ZRW1I1JefyhxrEhBMOCy9wn48medqeIpbmxP5GhQWG3zDLPPrnEU6c1N476Vd0rQpqw&sensor=false&key=API_KEY

I have noticed that most of the articles advise to use server key or browser key. But I don't see any server or browser key option available on api console.

I hope someone will be able to help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Dont expose your api key public, you should remove it later.**

I think you didn't enable google place service correctly.

Go to https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key , click get a key and select your project. you should wait a few minutes and try again with new api key.

take a look at https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-details to get place detail without creating your own asynctask

Comment: I have removed the API_KEY from the question. I think I enabled Google Places API_KEY properly. I did it twice to make sure accuracy. Google Maps and my current location are being shown but not current places when I click nearby hospitals. I can't figure out what went wrong. @quanlt

Comment: I just figured out the problem. Actually I was restricting  Google Places API Web Service with Android restriction. That's why it was not working. I read the developers guide again. Thanks for your help. @quanlt